# Custom row in wxListCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is it possible to use/create a custom row for wxListCtrl?
I need to show a dinamic list composed by more elements (text, progressbar, buttons). Something like this:

1 - text - progress-bar - button1, button2, button3, button 4

2 - text - progress-bar - button1, button2, button3, button 4

...

The documentation only explains how to create a text-based wxListCtrl. Anyone knows how to create it?

Comment: SO has a proper tags system (which you did use) - no need to put them in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [wxDataViewCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html) for anything beyond simple text (with maybe an icon in the first column).